# Running a jar included in an OSGi bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, osgi

The situation is that I need to package a runnable jar, X.jar into an OSGi bundle. The jar itself can not be modified and OSGi is mandatory as X.jar is to be distributed and run via a software program that requires OSGi bundles. The application contained in X.jar is to communicate over a network with another application.

My plan was to create an OSGi bundle with eclipse and then include X.jar in it. But the problem is that X.jar is not detected. If I instead try to access a copy of X.jar on my file system it works.   My bundle file structure:

```
 -\MyBundle
   -\META-INF
     -\MANIFEST.MF
   -\src
     -\mybundle
       -\Activator.class
   -\X.jar
```

Activator:

```
 public void start(BundleContext context)  {
    Thread XThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar X.jar");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      };
 }
```

Manifest.MF

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
 Bundle-Name: Bundle
 Bundle-SymbolicName: myBundle
 Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
 Bundle-Activator: com.ericsson.mas.Activator
 Bundle-ClassPath: .,X.jar
 Bundle-Vendor: BundleVendor
 Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
 Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
```

I suspect that there is some problem with my Bundle-ClassPath, but it seems correct when I search around. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: I am aware that this goes completely against OSGi's philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run it as an external java process, you will need to extract the jar from your bundle and point to the extracted jar. Your [bundle data file](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getDataFile%28java.lang.String%29) storage is a good place to extract the bundle. Putting the jar on the class path only helps if you want to load the classes directly in your activator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run it by calling the declared main class directly, no need to extract it and run another java process.
So take a look in the X.jars manifest, ther should be a Main declared. then in your activator, simply call:

```
the.package.from.x.MainClassX.main(new String[] {});
```

inside your thread.